# How to repeat alerm specific day of week in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i want to get alert of specific day in week using Alarm manager in android.
for example :- 
i have seven checkbox sunday to saturday. if i check monday , wednesday,friday , alarm play only threes day monday , wednesday & friday.

Any have Idea ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                    String today = null;
                    if (day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5
                            || day == 6) {

                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                                pendingIntent);
                    }
```

just write this code in your ok button..this code is succesfully runn in my apps

Comment: I don't think this actually works. It will set an alarm that goes off every day, but only when the button is pressed on a weekday.